# Trying to borrow variable binding from outside of loop

Tags: rust

I'm rewriting an average calculator from my Java textbook in Rust. It uses a loop to ask for several inputs, but I think I've run into an issue with ownership (as there's a `let grade` inside the loop), so I'm trying to get a better understanding.

When I declare `grade` outside the loop, only the first input value is recorded: every subsequent `grade` value becomes 0, regardless of input. If I declare `grade` inside the loop, every input value is recorded properly.

Is there a way to use borrowing that will let me declare `grade` outside the loop, and still have this little program work?

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut total: u32 = 0;
    let mut count: u32 = 0;
    let mut grade = String::new(); //This one

    while count < 5 {
        println!("Enter number:");

        io::stdin().read_line(&mut grade)
            .expect("failed.");

        let grade: u32 = match grade.trim().parse() {
            Ok(num) => num,
            Err(_) => 0,
        };

        total = total + grade;
        count = count + 1;
    }
    println!("Tot: {}\nAvg: {}", total, total as f64/count as f64);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`read_line` *appends* to the string you're reading into, so if you input 1 and then 2, `grade` will contain `1\n2` or something to that effect. This can't be parsed as an integer so the match below will always return 0. The solution is to empty the string before reading: `grade.clear();`

Comment: This fixed the problem, and taught me something about read_line. Top notch!