# Trying to borrow variable binding from outside of loop in Rust

Tags: loops, rust, borrowing

```rust
    // I want to use this...
    let group = svg::node::element::Group::new();

    for (index, character) in label_string.char_indices() {

        let character = svg::node::Text::new(character);

        let text = svg::node::element::Text::new()
        .set("x", 0 + 16 * index)
        .set("y", 20)
        .set("font-family", "Hack")
        .set("font-size", 16)
        .set("fill", color::color(foreground_color))
        .add(character);

        // ...inside this for loop.
        group.add(text);

    }
```

But I am told `use of moved value: group` because `value moved here, in previous iteration of loop`.

Which makes sense. But I can't figure out how to just borrow `group` instead. The `for` syntax doesn't give me any way do this, and these haven't work either:

```rust
    for (index, character) in label_string.char_indices() {
        ...
        let group_ref = &group;
        group_ref.add(text);
    }
```

```rust
    let group_ref = &group;
    for (index, character) in label_string.char_indices() {
        ...
        group_ref.add(text);
    }
```

Note: [Trying to borrow variable binding from outside of loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39004011/trying-to-borrow-variable-binding-from-outside-of-loop) doesn't answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`svg::node::element::Group::add`](https://docs.rs/svg/0.9.1/svg/node/element/struct.Group.html#method.add) has the following signature:

```rust
impl Group {
    pub fn add<T>(self, node: T) -> Self
    where
        T: Node,
    { /* ... */ }
}
```

From this signature we can see that the method takes `self` by value (not by reference, like `&self` or `&mut self`), which means that when you call `group.add(text)` from within your loop, you move the value out of the `group` variable (since the `add` method needs to take ownership). By the next time iteration of the loop, there is no value in the variable, so the compiler will complain.

However, we can also see that the method returns  `Self`, which indicates that we get a new value that we can just re-assign to `group`. That way, by the end of the iteration (and beginning of the next) we will have a value in the `group` variable that has not been moved out:

```rust
// note that we need this to be mut now, since we're reassigning within the loop
let mut group = svg::node::element::Group::new();

for (index, character) in label_string.char_indices() {
    // ...

    // since `group.add()` takes ownership of `group`, but returns a new value,
    // we can just reassign to `group`, so that it is present for the next iteration
    group = group.add(text);

}
```

Comment: This did it. So when the compiler told me that group had been moved to that line, it didn't mean inside the for loop (like I thought), it meant inside add(). Basically, the problem was not what I thought it was. Thanks!

Comment: @MadEmperorYuri Well, it _did_ mean inside the for loop. You called add() there, inside the loop. I wouldn't think of it moving as "inside" add(), it's moved as you call add() so you even have the privilege of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

[svg::node::element::Group::add](https://docs.rs/svg/0.9.1/svg/node/element/struct.Group.html#method.add) function takes first argument as self and return Self.

Code can be fixed as

```
let mut group = svg::node::element::Group::new();
    ^^^
//...

// in for loop
group = group.add(text);
^^^^^^^
```